# how to deserialize the property which has xml value but rest are json values

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-functions, jsonserializer

I have an azure function and which receives the request as below . One of the property has xml value . But when I desearialize it to json ,i'm getting the error.

```
{
    "policyVersionedApiName": "petstoreoperationpolicyapi",
    "operationPolicies": [
        {
            "policyFormat": "rawxml",
            "operationId": "createUsersWithArrayInput",
             "policyValue": "<policies> <inbound> <base/> <ip-filter action="allow"> <address>10.100.7.1</address> </ip-filter> </inbound> </policies>",
        }
       
    ]
}
```

Comment: please share more detail about the error

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace double quotes inside of json string by escape double quoutes

```
json = json.Replace("\">", "\\\">").Replace("=\"", "=\\\"");
```

If you need , you can convert xml to json too

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml((string)jsonParsed["operationPolicies"][0]["policyValue"]);
    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("policies");

    jsonParsed["operationPolicies"][0]["policyValue"] = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node));
    
    json = jsonParsed.ToString();
```

a new json

```
{
  "policyVersionedApiName": "petstoreoperationpolicyapi",
  "operationPolicies": [
    {
      "policyFormat": "rawxml",
      "operationId": "createUsersWithArrayInput",
      "policyValue": {
        "policies": {
          "inbound": {
            "base": null,
            "ip-filter": {
              "@action": "allow",
              "address": "10.100.7.1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I’m looking for generic solution because it changes in every request .

Comment: @RameshBaddam It is a generic solution.

Comment: Sorry for making you confused . I wanted xml value to be as is . I do not want  to split into individual properties . But the string should be as is

Comment: @RameshBaddam You don't need to split it, just use the first line of my code.

Comment: its not working all the xml content. Moreover the policy can contain c# code as well<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rate-limit-by-key  calls="10"
              renewal-period="60"
              increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200)"
              counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)"
              remaining-calls-variable-name="remainingCallsPerIP"/>
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>

Comment: one more example <policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <quota  calls="1000" bandwidth="4000" renewa-period="3600"/>

              
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>

Comment: @RameshBaddam I can create a string analisator to fix it, but it is  a big job, and I am not a free coder to do it for you. Much easier to fix  this json in the place where it is created.